# How to tell whether a JAR was built with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to tell (at least some of the time) whether a JAR was built with Gradle?

I’m am looking for a distinguishing feature similar to Ant’s `Ant-Version` `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` entry or Maven’s `META-INF/maven/…/pom.properties` JAR entry.

Note: I am **not** interested in “making up” a custom distinguishing feature (like my own manifest entry), but rather in determining whether a JAR found “in the wild” was built with Gradle, so any answer must point to an already established convention that is adhered to at least some of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Gradle by default is transparent, like a build tool should be.